# Sudo dpkg --configure -a explanation

Tags: command-line, updates

What exactly gets changed with this command? I tried installing [bum](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/bum.8.html) and the terminal tells me to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  .

Comment: What changes is that any packages that are *unconfigured* get (and become) *configured*. Apt tells you to run this command only if it has discovered a package management problem. Unconfigured packages on your system may (or may not) indicate a serious problem.

Comment: If you need more explanation, can you edit / comment your question? If my answer helps you, please mark/tick it as **Accepted**, so it would be easier for further readers

Answer (score 2):

Here are an explanation of the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command (all information is available in the `man` file, each of which is web linked below) :

- [sudo](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/sudo.8.html) gives root privilege to your command (necessary for `dpkg` command`)
- [dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dpkg.1.html) is a package manager, notably used for Debian and Debian-derived distros such as Ubuntu; it's an alternative way to install package next to `apt` (`apt` use internally `dpkg` command, but is easier to use due to repository automatic management)
- `--configure -a` is an option of dpkg. In this case, it tells dpkg to just do the configuration of **all** *non configured package* (`-a` is here to say **all**); globally, all unpackaged packages not now installed would be installed by using this option

NB :`--pending` option behind `--configure` is equivalent to `-a`

If you don't really understand some part, just comment my answer

Comment: *"[`dpkg` is] an alternative way to install package next to apt"* - that's not completely correct. `apt` uses `dpkg` internally, it just acts as a front-end and adds things like repository management on top.